# banning the user to visit a url before visiting a particular url?

Tags: php, html, session, localhost

I have made a quiz game using html & php and have URL as `"localhost/game/ques1.php"`,`"localhost/game/ques2.php"`.

I have used sessions in  it but a user can go the next question without answering question 1 by changing URL from `localhost/game/ques1.php` to `localhost/game/ques2.php`.

How to stop user doing that ??

Comment: in `ques1.php` just set a variable in session like `$_SESSION['lastQuestion']=1`. Then in `ques2.php` just check to see if `$_SESSION['lastQuestion'] == $currentQuestion - 1` where `$currentQuestion` relates to what page they are viewing. Then when `ques2.php` is loaded, set `lastQuestion` to 2 so you can do the same test on 3 and so on.

Comment: It worked bro...thank u vry much for d help

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'd do these things on a single page, but if you're sold on not doing it that way, you have a couple of options.

1. You could look into posting data to the questions as you go (include some hidden field that indicates the user started on question 1).
2. You could also include some dynamically generated token that you pass via query parameter to question 2.
3. You could use session variables to mark that each page was already requested, although I can imagine a number of ways that that could fail.
4. You could save cookies, although that's not a great way of doing it either.

I'd really look into just doing it all on one page. You don't have to show everything at once, I bet you could make the UI look very similar to what you've got now. But it'd be cleaner and probably load faster (since you wouldn't have to load all of your `head` and master page (or whatever) content for every question).